# Python Telebot. Не сохраняется значение в переменную

Tags: python, telebot

Когда пользователь пишет боту любое сообщение, переменная 'a' должна принимать значение '1', но при выводе этой переменной в конце кода, ее значение остается None. Недавно стал изучать написание ботов и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

```
a = None    
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def adw(message):
    a = 1
    
print(a)
```

Comment: Это нужно примерно никогда. В чем ваша реальная задача?

Comment: Записать в переменные то, что напишет пользователь и в будущем отправить администратору бота

Comment: А зачем записывать это в переменную, если сообщение сразу можно отправить администратору? Что будет в случае, если 2 человека напишут боту +- одновременно?

Answer (score 1):

возможно стоит использовать a как глобальную переменную

````
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def adw(message):
    global a
    a = 1

adw()
print(a)```
````

Comment: 1. Не вызывает функцию
2. Переменная у него объявлена глобально, ему нужно просто вызвать функцию и всё.

Comment: Появляется ошибка     name 'a' is assigned to before global declaration